# Psycopg2 query returning Decimal('value')

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a query in Python querying a postgresql database (via psycopg2). My code is returning the value as Decimal('VALUE'). Is there any way to convert this in the database?
Code Sample:

```
query = "SELECT id FROM table;"
cur.execute(query)
results = cur.fetchall()
# Results = Decimal('some value')
```

Is there anyway to convert this to just show the value without the "Decimal()"? Maybe I have my schema set up wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

what you're seeing is the `repr()` of a [`decimal.Decimal()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) value, which can precisely represent decimal values, a feature not available to [`float`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)s.  There's no loss of utility, though, if you want to see a nice string representation, say, to 6 decimal places, just format it the way you would a `float`, with `str` or `format`!

```
In [7]: str(decimal.Decimal('0.1'))
Out[7]: '0.1'

In [13]: "{0:0.6f}".format(decimal.Decimal('0.1'))
Out[13]: '0.100000'
```

Answer (score 15):

Very annoying issue, came accross it myself. I solved it in the SQL by casting the column to float. In your query:

```
query = "SELECT id::float as id FROM table;"
cur.execute(query)
results = cur.fetchall()
# Results = Decimal('some value')
```